# Sharing a link to Facebook wall posted via FB.ui javascript API

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I manually post a link to my Wall via the Facebook website, I can see three links below to "like", "comment", or "share" the post.  However, if I have an app, and post a link via the Javascript FB.ui dialog, I only see options to "like" or "comment" without the ability to "share" the post.

Is there any way to enable the "share" link for wall posts via API?

Comment: you ever get an answer to this?  I have the same question up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963760/get-share-link-on-facebook-posts

Answer (score 0):

Hey i know it might be too late to help you but it might be helpful to others who are facing the same issue and come here looking for a solution.
If you use the Graph API to post it will post in the way you require( "like", "comment", or "share")